# How to configure "Download As..."

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

After a day of research I managed to do a custom template for nbconvert that does what I needed to do (hide the input cells as part of a pdf conversion). However this only works in the command line. I'd like to be able to do this by chosing from the export menu, since exporting with or without output is something I'll switch frequenly.

I did some more research and found out that by adding

```
c.LatexExporter.template_file = 'noinput.tplx'
```

To my jupyter_notebook_config.py file should update the "Download As..." PDF with latex option, however it doesnt seem to do anything. Maybe there are some additional settings I should activate in the configuration file? Documentation is rather unclear in how this particular menu works.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51211958/9235907). When you use nbconvert from the command line does it use your `'noinput.tplx'` template by default?