# Right place to put custom nbconvert templates

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jinja2, nbconvert

I've made a custom nbconvert template and want it to be accessible from any folder where I launch `nbconvert` utility. Where should I put my template?

I couldn't find anything in official docs. I have already tried usual places for jupyter configs, like `/usr/share/jupyter`, `~/.local/share/jupyter`, `~/.jupyter`, to no avail.

The only place I've found so far is the folder where python package lives:

```
$ pip show nbconvert | grep Location | cut -d" " -f2
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

If I create `nbconvert/templates/html` directory there and put my template in it, `nbconvert --to html --template <my_template_name> ...` works fine. But this is an ugly hack which I'll need to re-do every time I update nbconvert.

Seems that I can provide nbconvert with environment variable, but I would prefer to avoid this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `nbconvert` to look for your template by creating an [`jupyter_nbconvert_config.py`](https://github.com/minrk/.jupyter/blob/master/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py) file and storing it in `~/.jupyter`.

I use this for LaTeX--here's what my file looks like:

```
import os
c = get_config()

c.LatexExporter.template_path = ['.', os.path.expanduser('~/.jupyter/templates')]
c.LatexExporter.template_file = 'custom_latex.tplx'
```

Assuming you template extends an existing one, you need to include `'.'` when setting `template_path` so it knows where to look for the standard templates.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in nbconvert 6+? I've [tried everything I can think of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127278/what-is-the-proper-way-to-specify-a-custom-template-path-for-jupyter-nbconvert-v), but I can't seem to make it work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#Custom-Templates).

The recommended place to save custom templates, so that they are globally accessible to nbconvert, is your jupyter data directories:

- share/jupyter

  - nbconvert

    - templates

      - html
      - latex

Alternately

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_path
print(jupyter_path('nbconvert','templates'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when installing `nbconvert` to a custom location using:

```
pip install --target=/foooooo/baaaaar nbconvert
```

You just need to set a [`JUPYTER_PATH` environment variable](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_PATH).

```
JUPYTER_PATH=/foooooo/baaaaar/share/jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to editing `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` you can also edit `jupyter_nbconvert_config.json`. First assert that `~/.jupyter` is in the config path with `jupyter --path`. Then insert in `jupyter_nbconvert_config.json` a template directory. I added a subfolder `custome_templates` to mine:

```
{
  "Exporter": {
    "template_path": [
      ".", 
      "/home/moutsopoulosg/miniconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/templates",
      "/home/moutsopoulosg/.jupyter/custom_templates"
    ], 
    ...
  },
  "version": 1
}
```

Then `nbconvert --template mytemplate Untitiled.ipynb` picks up my template.